# Large number of floating stubs in one binary in IDA Pro

Tags: ida

I am looking at a statically linked ARM binary from a Busybox system.

After IDA is done with the initial analysis, I end up with a lot of subroutines with these strange floating stubs. There are no references to get to them, and I can't see what function they serve.

Is this simply an IDA issue?

[image: Floating stubs]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there was a switch/jump table statement which was not recognized so there are no cross-references to these code fragments. Switch to text mode and look at the code before all of them.